# Wrong option login in Magento Enterprise

Tags: ee-1.13, enterprise-1.13

After Login into Magento as a customer from frontend, the label Logout is changed to Login; if I click anywhere on the page like Filters or home page or products.

I think, problem is caused by Magento cache?

Comment: did you try disabling the FPC?

Comment: If you open up the F12 tools on your browser you can delete the session cookies for your site, try that and then you know whether the problem is with your browser or the server.

Comment: Does this happen in the default theme? Do you have a custom CE theme that you have installed? Do you have any custom hole punching for cache?